# Problems with Spring boot and Java JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am facing the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-12T21:33:06.984+03:00 ERROR 10508 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'supermarketApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.softeng.supermarket.SupermarketApplication.main(SupermarketApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:605) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:594) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:608) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:190) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1730) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:259) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:589) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

My files are as follows:

pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

User class

```
package com.softeng.supermarket.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
    @Size(min=5,max=15,message = "Username must be between 5 and 15 characters")
    private String Username;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
    @Size(min=8,max=15,message = "Password must be between 8 and 15 characters")
    private String Password;

    private String Email;
    private String Phone;

    private String Firstname;

    private String Lastname;
    private Boolean isAdmin;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email, String phone, String firstname, String lastname, Boolean isAdmin) {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }
     + getters/setters
}
```

UserRepository

```
package com.softeng.supermarket.repositories;

import com.softeng.supermarket.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    List<User> findByUsername(String name);
    List<User> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
}
```

and finally main

```
package com.softeng.supermarket;

import com.softeng.supermarket.models.User;
import com.softeng.supermarket.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.softeng.supermarket.controllers")
@ComponentScan("com.softeng.supermarket.models")
@ComponentScan("com.softeng")
public class SupermarketApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SupermarketApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args){
        User user1 = new User("Antonis","test123","test@tester.com","6971989277","Antonios","Fritzelas",false);
        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.findByUsername("Antonis").forEach(
                val -> System.out.println(val)
        );
    }
}
```

I have tried various versions of starter jpa, spring boot and hibernate and keep having issues. What could be the problem? I have searched various forums but could not find any solutions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a recent version of spring boot but, but the other dependencies versions are not compatible with the version of Spring Boot. try to remove the version elements from the XML, and Spring Boot's dependency management will automatically select compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use username as id. Please try to generate id automatically. Also if you want to make username unique, you can set it using `column` annotation:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String username;


  // Dont forget to update your repository for Long id:
   public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
```